# In Oracle, How do I alter a user that have a special character in the name?

Tags: oracle, special-characters, alter-table, user-accounts

I am using Oracle 11g and I need to unlock an specific user but this user have a dot in the name.For Example lets say my user name is 'foo.mock'. I know that adding this kind of characters in user names is not a good practice but I dont administrate the database.

So I tried with

```
Alter user foo.mock account unlock;
```

and with

```
Alter user 'foo.mock' account unlock;
```

and also tried to save the name in a variable and then use that variable in alter query but nothing worked.

Any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can enclose it in double quotes, but you need to match the case from `dba_users`, which is usually uppercase but may not be if it was created quoted:

```
alter user "FOO.MOCK" account unlock;
```

[Read more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) about quoted and non-quoted identifiers.